# Factor rational function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Is there a factorization $$\frac{1}{1-wz} = f(w)g(z),$$ where $f$ does not depend on $z$ and $g$ does not depend on $w$? My assumptions are that $w,z \in \mathbb{C}$ and that $f,g:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. The factorization does not need to hold for all $(w,z)\in\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$, I would also be interested in subsets of $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ for which it might hold.

Comment: well you could have $f$ and $g$ be random rational fractions then the thing would be true on a curve.

Answer (score 3):

On $\Bbb C×\Bbb C$ you would simultaneously have
$$
f(1)g(z)=\frac1{1-z}\text{ and }f(-1)g(z)=\frac1{1+z}
$$
among many others. The same function can not have at the same time a pole and a finite value at the same point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you think of a similar obvious contradiction if we say restrict $w$ such that $\Re(w) > 0$ and $z$ such that $\Re(z) < 0$?

Comment: You would still get $f(a)f(b)g(z)=\frac{f(a)}{1-bz}=\frac{f(b)}{1-az}$ which would require $f(a)=f(b)$ and $af(a)=bf(b)$, which is only possible for $a=b$, thus $f$ could only be defined in one point.

Answer (score 3):

Such a factorization does not exist if one of the functions is differentiable. Suppose it existed. You could therefore write 
$$\tag{1}
1-wz=F(w)G(z).$$
Assuming that $F$ is differentiable, taking the derivative with respect to $w$ yields $-z=F'(w)G(z)$, so 
$$F(w)=\frac{-zw}{G(z)}+C(z).$$
As LutzL points out, this relation can be evaluated at $w=0$, showing that $C$ is actually a constant (save for the points $z$ at which $G(z)=0$, which are at most countably many). So we write $C$ instead of $C(z)$. Substituting this back in (1) we obtain $G(z)=\frac1C$, and thus the contradiction $$\tag{!!}1-wz=\frac{F(w)}{C}.$$

Comment: You need to make the constant a function of $z$. But still, for $G(z)\ne 0$ you get $F(0)=C(z)$ regaining that $C$ is constant except possibly at isolated points.